# Find the isomorphism type

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, group-presentation

Consider the abelian group $G$ generated by $a$, $b$ and $c$ and determined by the following relations

\begin{aligned} 3 a+9 b+9 c &=0 \\-3 b+9 c &=0 \end{aligned}

determine the isomorphism type of the group $G$.

I should use The Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups. I think I should determine the orders of the generators, but i I do not see how.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The relations give $b=3c$ and $a=-12c$. Therefore we can omit $a$ and $b$ from the presentation and we have no relations remaining for $c$:

$G=<c>$.

Comment: How do you get $b=3c$?

Comment: Using the second relation; we can assume $3 \neq 0$.

Comment: If I add 3 times the second relation to the first relation we get t $3(a+12c)=0$, can we conclude that $a=-12c$? I am missing something?

Comment: That‘s one way to do it, that‘s correct!